# Model performance in quantile modelling

Tags: regression, data-mining, predictive-models, quantile-regression

I am using quantile regression (for example via `gbm` or `quantreg` in R) - not focusing on the median but instead an upper quantile (e.g. 75th). Coming from a predictive modeling background, I want to measure how well the model fits on a test set and be able to describe this to a business user. My question is how? In a typical setting with a continuous target I could do the following:

- Calculate the overall RMSE
- Decile the data set by the predicted value and compare the average
  actual to the average predicted in each decile.
- Etc.

What can be done in this case, where there really is no actual value (i don't think at least) to compare the prediction to?

Here is an example code:

```
install.packages("quantreg")
library(quantreg)

install.packages("gbm")
library(gbm)

data("barro")

trainIndx<-sample(1:nrow(barro),size=round(nrow(barro)*0.7),replace=FALSE)
train<-barro[trainIndx,]
valid<-barro[-trainIndx,]

modGBM<-gbm(y.net~., # formula
            data=train, # dataset
            distribution=list(name="quantile",alpha=0.75), # see the help for other choices
            n.trees=5000, # number of trees
            shrinkage=0.005, # shrinkage or learning rate,
            # 0.001 to 0.1 usually work
            interaction.depth=5, # 1: additive model, 2: two-way interactions, etc.
            bag.fraction = 0.5, # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
            train.fraction = 0.5, # fraction of data for training,
            # first train.fraction*N used for training
            n.minobsinnode = 10, # minimum total weight needed in each node
            cv.folds = 5, # do 3-fold cross-validation
            keep.data=TRUE, # keep a copy of the dataset with the object
            verbose=TRUE) # don’t print out progress

best.iter<-gbm.perf(modGBM,method="cv")

pred<-predict(modGBM,valid,best.iter)
```

Now what - since we don't observe the percentile of the conditional distribution?

**Add:**

I hypothesized several methods and I would like to know if they are correct and if there are better ones - also how to interpret the first:

1. Calculate the average value from the loss functions:

   ```
   qregLoss<-function(actual, estimate,quantile)
   {
      (sum((actual-estimate)*(quantile-((actual-estimate)<0))))/length(actual)

   }
   ```

   This is the loss function for quantile regression - but how do we interpret the value?
2. Should we expect that if for example we are calculating the 75th percentile that on a test set, the predicted value should be greater than the actual value around 75% of the time?

Are there other methods formal or heuristic to describe how well the model predicts new cases?

Comment: Section 3 in [this paper](http://econ.ucsd.edu/~ikomunje/files/papers/hdbk_quantile.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: @tchakravarty I think that link has gone dead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A useful reference may be [Haupt, Kagerer, and Schnurbus (2011)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02664763.2011.573542) discussing the use of quantile-specific measures of predictive accuracy based on cross-validations for various classes of quantile regression models.